# Python and postgis, trying to figure out data types

Tags: python, postgis

I have a simple sql I am running from python that gets all these items from a table (mostly the mpoly I am curious about).  Which is a geometry.

```
cur = self.db.cursor()
cur.execute('select St_AsText(ST_Centroid(mpoly)) from swsite_cesiumentity')
allEntities = cur.fetchall()
```

Then I can get the info out:

```
    print ' ***'
    print allEntities[0]
    print '----'
```

and it will give me:

`Row(st_astext='POINT(-87.266150008217 30.0857181963441)')`

That is well and good, but I try to use this data to then get all the points that are so far away from the above point and I do not know how to use the types I have in the sql query I want to use.

Tried this:

```
for currentEntity in allEntities:
    print currentEntity
    cur2  = self.db.cursor()
    cur2.execute ('SELECT * FROM swsite_cesiumentity WHERE ST_Distance_Sphere(mpoly, ST_GeomFromText(' + currentEntity.st_astext + ')) <= radius_mi * 1609.34)) from swsite_cesiumentity')
    list = cur2.fetchall()
    print list
```

It doesn't like what I am feeding the second sql statement:

```
pg.ProgrammingError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "30.0857181963441"
LINE 1: ...ere(mpoly, ST_GeomFromText(POINT(-87.266150008217 30.0857181...
                                                             ^

C02RH2U9G8WM:ingest sth$
```

Comment: Don't [cross-post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/226860/1872)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WKT is text, and text in SQL goes in single-quotes `'like this'`, thus:

```
sql = "SELECT ... ST_GeomFromText('" + wkt + "') ..."
```

will make the WKT as text, i.e.  `SELECT ... ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1 2)') ...`

Depending on the library (you never said—was it psycopg2?), you should instead use a parameterized statement to avoid text formatting errors and [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities.